# Error Xcode Undefined symbol while running IOS build

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

While running the IOS build on Flutter I am getting strange error like below

```
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAPIClient

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPSetupIntentConfirmParams

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAppInfo

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentIntentParams

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentMethodParams

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPTheme

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentMethodAddress

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPCardParams

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAddCardViewController

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAddress

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _STPStringFromCardBrand

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentHandler

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPBankAccountParams

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentConfiguration

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentMethodCardParams

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPUserInformation

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPRedirectContext

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPSourceParams

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

My application is a basic simple application with stripe integration. Can anyone help me to get rid of this freaky error. I am trying to run it on simulator and tried all devices to run but unable resolve.

Comment: The community will likely need more specifics to get an understanding of what you've done so far and what you're trying to do. I see that you included the flutter and dart tags on this post, are you working with those, or are you directly integrating with the Stripe SDK?

Comment: @toby yes I am using flutter.

Comment: I having the same issue after adding firebase_analytics 9.3.0